# Scaling Amazon EC2 - application properties management (Spring Boot)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, horizontal-scaling

I use this instruction:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

to deploy Spring Boot application on EC2 Ubuntu server.
I'm going to move configuration from application.properties file to environment variables using:
spring.datasource.password=${MYAPP_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

If I'll make many copies of this configuration, how to manage it? For example, change datasource password on all instances?
I'll have to do it manually ? It'll going to be tedious, and error prone work...

Comment: I think you'll have to invest some time in automation. Two things that come to mind can solve your problems i.e. Ansible and Docker. Or even plain AMIs with MYAPP_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD set in environment variables.

Comment: Ok, so if I start 10 servers using my custom AMI with MYAPP_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD, and then, I change datasource password, I should: change password only once in AMI  
-> kill all 10 servers -> start 10 new servers  
?

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: Thanks @anand1st for your support!

Answer (score 0):

"I think you'll have to invest some time in automation. Two things that come to mind can solve your problems i.e. Ansible and Docker. Or even plain AMIs with MYAPP_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD set in environment variables"

@anand1st answer solves the problem.